# Why is DataRow not found in DataTable

Tags: c#, database

New to data manipulation using `DataTable`, `DataColumn`, `DataRow`. Why is `employee` not found in the `DataTable`? I was expected `indexFound` to have the value "2", and when I debug the values all look correct.

```
// Manually create a new DataTable
DataTable dtEmployees = new DataTable("Employee");

// Add columns
dtEmployees.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
dtEmployees.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dtEmployees.Columns.Add("Salary", typeof(int));

// Add rows to the table
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(52, "Sally", 29000);
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(63, "Harry", 22000);
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(72, "Alain", 23000);
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(110, "Pete", 24500);

// Look for an employee...
int index = 2;
Console.WriteLine("(index of DataRow({0}) should return {0})", index);
DataRow employee = dtEmployees.NewRow();
employee["ID"] = dtEmployees.Rows[index]["ID"];
employee["Name"] = dtEmployees.Rows[index]["Name"];
employee["Salary"] = dtEmployees.Rows[index]["Salary"];

int indexFound = dtEmployees.Rows.IndexOf(employee);
if (indexFound != -1)
    Console.Write("  Employee has index {0}", indexFound); // Was expecting this...
else
    Console.Write("  Employee not found in table..."); // ...but actually get this. Why??
```

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) didn't provide any meaningful help.

Comment: The code doesn't add the NewRow to the Rows collection in the Datatable. So asking to find a row not added results in no row found. _dtEmployees.Rows.Add(employee);_

Comment: Thanks Steve, that's makes sense and what I thought, but I don't fully understand. Why do you have to add the `DataRow` to the `DataRowCollection` before you can search for it? How does one use `DataTable::Rows::IndexOf` to search for a `DataRow` created on-the-fly?

Comment: Well, this is how it works. First you ask to create a NewRow (empty but with all the info about the datatype of each field), then you fill it and finally you add it back to the Rows collection where you can search of it. But, see my answer because having a datarow to search for is not very common, instead you search using some field value.

Comment: I believe AlainD tries to search for _another_  row in the table with the same values. But `DataRowCollection.IndexOf` searches for the same `DataRow` instance/object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DataRow needs to be added to the Rows collection of the Datatable if you want to find it in the collection with IndexOf, so you just need to add this line before searching the row

```
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(employee);
```

Of course this method (IndexOf) is of some value only if you have a row to search for. Usually if you want to search a Datatable the preferred way is through the Select method that could return a set of one or more rows using a search criteria that resembles a WHERE sql statement.

```
dtEmployees.Rows.Add(employee);
DataRow[] rows = dtEmployees.Select("ID = 72");
if(rows != null && rows.Length > 0)
{
     Console.WriteLine("rows found:" + rows.Length);
     foreach(DataRow r in rows)
        Console.WriteLine(r.Field<string>("name"));
}
```

Comment: OK, thanks...will try that out when I'm back at work tomorrow!